# How to skip field when empty in beanio?

Tags: java, bean-io

The requirement is to skip field when its empty.
eg -

```
    <segment name="seg1" class="com.company.bean.segmentBean" xmlType="none">   
            <field name="field1" xmlName= "fieldXml1" xmlType="attribute" maxLength="7" />
            <field name="field2" xmlName= "fieldX2l1" xmlType="attribute" maxLength="1" typeHandler="Handler" />
    </segment>
```

Lets assume that field2="". As the value of field2 is "". I would like to have the field skipped in segment. Basically the end result XML shouldnt display field2 as its empty("").

Answer (score 0):

You need the `lazy` attribute on field2. As stated in the [Reference Guide](https://beanio.github.io/docs/reference-guide/#a12-field)

> lazy - Set to true to convert empty field text to null before type conversion. For repeating fields bound to a collection, the collection will not be created if all field values are null or the empty String. Defaults to false.

This will make `field2 = null` and by default, most XML libraries will not output any null elements, `BeanIO` included.

Try this for field2:

```
<field name="field2" lazy="true" xmlName= "fieldX2l1" xmlType="attribute" maxLength="1" typeHandler="Handler" />
```

Most of the time, I also combine `lazy` with `trim`. From the docs:

> trim - Set to true to trim the field text before validation and type
> conversion. Defaults to false.

```
<field name="field2" lazy="true" trim="true" xmlName= "fieldX2l1" xmlType="attribute" maxLength="1" typeHandler="Handler" />
```